# How to excute the command on remote server in using SMBClient in java

Tags: java

I want excute the bat file on remote server from another server or local, I am able to connect the server by using SMBClient, But i dont know how to run/excute the command

Below sample of code for connecting the server.

```
            SMBClient client = new SMBClient();
            Connection connection = client.connect("SERVERNAME");
            AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext("USERNAME", "PASSWORD".toCharArray(), "DOMAIN");
            Session session = connection.authenticate(ac);
```

Comment: SMBclient is not support for command execution .                               https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj/issues/802